# How can I convert my json response in a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have this in my controller:

```
render json: gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment)
```

It returns something like that:

```
{"code"=>200, "data"=>{"barcode"=>"03399.75039 21000.000006 74992.301015 6 69020000002250", "link"=>"https://exmaple.com.br/emissao/110276_19_NAEMAL1/A4XB-110276-74992-XILE0"}}
```

I need to return a string. How can I convert it to a string?
I need return something like that:

```
"{"code"=>200, "data"=>{"barcode"=>"03399.75039 21000.000006 74992.301015 6 69020000002250", "link"=>"https://exmaple.com.br/emissao/110276_19_NAEMAL1/A4XB-110276-74992-XILE0"}}"
```

Comment: `to_s` works it will just escape the `"`

Answer (score 0):

`render text: gerencia.pay_charge(params: params, body: payment).to_json`